# Evaluating negative infinite tetration: $\lim\limits_{n\to-\infty}\,^n x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\log_x\left(…\log_x(0)\right)}_n=\,^{-\infty} x$

Tags: limits, complex-numbers, tetration, power-towers, experimental-mathematics

One can learn that for a [**power tower of height $n$**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration):

$$y=n\big\{x^{x^{x^…}}=\,^nx\implies \log_x(y)=\boxed{\log_x(\,^nx)=\,^{n-1}x}$$

giving a recursive relation. One might see that $n<-2$ cases are undefined, but using the [extended real numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) or limits, one can actually use the principal branch for the logarithm function for $x\ne0$:

$$\log_x(\,^1x)=\frac{\ln(\,^1 x)}{\ln(x)}=\,^{1-1}x=\,^0x=1\implies  \frac{\ln(1)}{\ln(x)}=\,^{0-1}x=\,^{-1}x =0$$

Here is when problems occur. We can define $\ln(-\infty)=\infty$ or $\ln(-\infty)=\ln(-1)+\ln(\infty)=\pi i+\infty$, but to stick with real values, like in

> [Does this limit exist or is undefined $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\ln\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x-3}\right)=\ln(-\infty)=\infty,$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251311/does-this-limit-exist-or-is-undefined?noredirect=1)

let us consider the simpler version of $\boxed{\ln(-\infty)=\infty}$. Note that I will not simplify the logarithms into the infinity to keep the domain as large as possible:

$$\frac{\ln(\,^{-1} x)}{\ln(x)}=\frac{\ln(0)}{\ln(x)}=\,^{{-1}-1}x=\,^{-2}x =-\frac{\infty}{\ln(x)}\\\implies \frac{\ln(\,^{-2} x)}{\ln(x)}= \frac{\ln\left(\frac{-\infty}{\ln(x)}\right)}{\ln(x)}=\,^{{-2}-1}x=\,^{-3}x = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{-\infty}{\ln(x)}\right)}{\ln(x)} = \frac{\infty-\ln(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}\\\implies \frac{\ln(\,^{-3} x)}{\ln(x)}=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\infty-\ln(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}\right)}{\ln(x)}=\,^{{-3}-1}x=\,^{-4}x = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{\infty-\ln(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}\right)}{\ln(x)}=\log_x\left(\infty-\ln(\ln(x))\right)-\log_x(\ln(x)) $$

and so on. This creates a couple questions using our aforementioned assumptions and [these Wolfram Functions conventions](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/03/). The question here is what would happen if we calculated:

$$\lim_{n\to-\infty}\,^n x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\log_x\left(…\log_x(0)\right)}_n=\,^{-\infty} x$$
which looks like [a W-Lambert function](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog2/09/):
$$-\frac{\text W_{-1}(-\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}= \lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\log_x\left(…\log_x(e)\right)}_n $$
using the same process and the recursive definition of:

$$\log_x(\,^nx)=\frac{\ln(\,^nx)}{\ln(x)}=\,^{n-1}x $$ Also, what is the range of this new *experimental* $\ \,^{-\infty} x\ $ function? I have listed the conventions that will be used, so there should be no confusion. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: First we might try to find $^{-2}x$. There may be a problem. See the discussion of extensions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).

Comment: What is $^n x$? You want me to watch the video to find out? The video is $>40$ min long and the guy there has a bad haircut.

Comment: @markvs The video is just a link, the goal is to use the reduction formula in the question.

Comment: **What is** $^n x$???

Comment: @markvs Did you see “ where one can learn that for a [**power tower of height $n$**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration):

$$y=n\big\{x^{x^{x^…}}\\=\,^nx\implies \log_x(y)=\log_x(\,^nx)=\,^{n-1}x$$”? It is one of many notations for tetration.

Comment: @TymaGaidash: The second equality there is a definition??

Comment: @markvs I am confused by what you want to know. That is the definition at the start of the question. It is an exponential tower with $n$ amount of $x$ in it.

Comment: No, the start of the question is this "The question is inspired from this video where one can learn that for a..."

Comment: @markvs I suggest you watch from 6 minutes to 13 minutes into the video to get the definitions. Let me edit.

Comment: As I said, the guy has a bad haircut. It is repulsive.  Make him change it (or change the guy altogether) and remake the video. Then I perhaps will have a few minutes to watch it.

Comment: If you would take the other definition of the iterated logarithm $\log°^h(z_0)=\log(\log°^{h-1}(z_0))$ with $\log°^0(z_0)=z_0$ *(and using the principal branch of the logarithm)* then the exceptional values for which your iterated logarithm runs into singularities are exactly that of $z_0 \in \{0,1,e,e^e,e^{e^e},\,^4e,\,^5e,...\}$. But when you use different $z_0$ as starting values you can apply that iterated logarithm when you allow logarithm of complex values. Then beginning with (complex) $z_0 $ near $0+0î$ or near $1+0î$ you get a hint what your wished limit goes to. (...)

Comment: (...)  I've once computed the iterates of the line $z_0 \in \{0+\varepsilon \ldots 1-\varepsilon\}$ and plotted the lines for the iterated logarithms as far as I could manage $\varepsilon \to 0$ with Pari/GP and got an interesting set of plots. Similarly with small imaginary parts of that $z_0$ . Anyway, one can see how this iterates to the complex fixpoint for base $e$; and can analoguously made with other bases. Don't know, though, whether this is trivial to you and so didn't compose an answer showing such plots.

Comment: (...) And the sequence of plots suggest, that once you define $\log(-\infty):= \pm \pi î+ \infty$ then the limit of this for the first three iterates is $+\infty \pm 0 î $ and all further iterates should have the same form. (Sorry, I didn't catch your question correctly at the beginning)

Comment: @markvs. Never watch people with bad haircut, bruhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: @TymaGaidash. I know about the channel. I was just joking that how markvs didn't watch the video because his hairstyle was repulsive to him or maybe he was just trolling.

Answer (score 1):

***(Not an answer, only an extension of my 2.nd comment)***

I show some iterates of the $\log()$ with base=$e$. Using my proposed definition for the
notation we see some initial values $z_0$ between $0$ and $1$ and their $h$'th iterates
$z_h$. I think it is easily extrapolatable, where the $h$'th iterates tend to, when
$z_0$ approaches either the initial value $0$ (or $1$, which is implied by your notation).
This is a q&d-computation with Pari/GP with internal precision of 200 dec digits.

```
               z_0                 z_0                z_0               z_0               z_0               z_0               z_0               z_0               z_0               z_0               z_0               z_0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                          
z_0           5.000E-26         5.000E-17   0.0000000005000        0.00005000            0.05000            0.5000  |            0.5000           0.9500             1.000             1.000             1.000             1.000  
z_1              -58.26            -37.53            -21.42            -9.903             -2.996           -0.6931  |           -0.6931         -0.05129       -0.00005000  -0.0000000005000        -5.000E-17        -5.000E-26  
z_2       4.065+3.142*I     3.625+3.142*I     3.064+3.142*I     2.293+3.142*I      1.097+3.142*I   -0.3665+3.142*I  |   -0.3665+3.142*I   -2.970+3.142*I    -9.903+3.142*I    -21.42+3.142*I    -37.53+3.142*I    -58.26+3.142*I  
z_3      1.637+0.6580*I    1.568+0.7140*I    1.479+0.7979*I    1.358+0.9403*I      1.202+1.235*I     1.151+1.687*I  |     1.151+1.687*I    1.464+2.328*I     2.341+2.834*I     3.075+2.996*I     3.629+3.058*I     4.066+3.088*I  
z_4     0.5675+0.3823*I   0.5440+0.4273*I   0.5191+0.4947*I   0.5020+0.6055*I    0.5443+0.7987*I   0.7142+0.9718*I  |   0.7142+0.9718*I    1.012+1.009*I    1.302+0.8805*I    1.457+0.7724*I    1.557+0.7003*I    1.630+0.6495*I  
z_5    -0.3794+0.5928*I  -0.3685+0.6658*I  -0.3326+0.7614*I  -0.2401+0.8786*I  -0.03400+0.9726*I   0.1873+0.9371*I  |   0.1873+0.9371*I  0.3571+0.7843*I   0.4521+0.5947*I   0.5002+0.4875*I   0.5350+0.4226*I   0.5624+0.3791*I  
z_6     -0.3512+2.140*I   -0.2732+2.076*I   -0.1853+1.983*I  -0.09336+1.838*I   -0.02715+1.606*I  -0.04541+1.373*I  |  -0.04541+1.373*I  -0.1488+1.144*I  -0.2917+0.9207*I  -0.3589+0.7725*I  -0.3831+0.6686*I  -0.3882+0.5930*I  
z_7      0.7742+1.733*I    0.7391+1.702*I    0.6888+1.664*I    0.6097+1.622*I     0.4737+1.588*I    0.3179+1.604*I  |    0.3179+1.604*I   0.1425+1.700*I  -0.03476+1.878*I   -0.1604+2.006*I   -0.2606+2.091*I   -0.3442+2.150*I  
z_8      0.6411+1.151*I    0.6180+1.161*I    0.5883+1.178*I    0.5495+1.211*I     0.5049+1.281*I    0.4917+1.375*I  |    0.4917+1.375*I   0.5342+1.487*I    0.6301+1.589*I    0.6992+1.651*I    0.7454+1.695*I    0.7783+1.729*I  
z_9      0.2756+1.063*I    0.2740+1.082*I    0.2754+1.108*I    0.2852+1.145*I     0.3197+1.195*I    0.3787+1.227*I  |    0.3787+1.227*I   0.4576+1.226*I    0.5363+1.193*I    0.5837+1.170*I    0.6160+1.156*I    0.6400+1.148*I  
                 .                 .                 .                 .                  .                 .                    .                .                 .                 .                 .                 .   
                 .                 .                 .                 .                  .                 .                    .                .                 .                 .                 .                 .   
                 .                 .                 .                 .                  .                 .                    .                .                 .                 .                 .                 .   
z_oo        <fixpoint>        <fixpoint>        <fixpoint>        <fixpoint>         <fixpoint>        <fixpoint>   |       <fixpoint>       <fixpoint>        <fixpoint>        <fixpoint>        <fixpoint>        <fixpoint>
```

Below there is a plot of the iterates $z_h = \log°^h(z_0)$ of the line $z_0 \in \varepsilon \ldots 1-\varepsilon$
The lines $z_0 , z_1=\log°^1(z_0),z_2 =\log°^2(z_0)$ are not displayed. The line for $z_3$ is the red curve in the right half looking roughly like a $\sqrt x $ curve, the line for $z_4$ is the green curve most neighboured at the $z_3$ curve and the positive real axis, whose both ends tend to $+ \infty + 0 \pi î$.
This plot should work as a suggestion how -if at all- that infinite iteration could be defined most meaningfully.
[image]

Additional remark: the curves could not have been drawn out to the values $x \approx 9$ by the iteration of logarithms alone; two times iterated back we had a real value of $\exp(\exp(9.4)) \approx 2.1 E 4750$ which gives then a limit for $z_0$ near $0$ which I wouldn't have used from the beginning . But there is a functional relation between the real- and the imaginary value in the $z_3$ curve which allows to compute (and plot) the curve to arbitrary real-argument larger than this roughly 1.2-value. From that the iterated logarithms for a far wider interval of the $z_3$ can be computed. *(Sorry, don't have that functional relation at hand at the moment, but was simply derived from the trigonometric formula for the complex logarithm).*

Comment: (+1) @Gottfried Thanks for the insights, but the goal is to have $$\log_x^{\circ h}(0)$$ which may diverge, but has interesting behavior for complex values. A limit as $h\to 0$ may also work if that is what you did here.

Comment: Tyma, thanks for the comment and the upvote! The point of the introducing table is surely away from your question (I got it obviously not correct immediately). But the point of the plot is indeed to give suggestions for the locus of the endpoints $\log_x^{\circ h}(1-\varepsilon)$ and $\log_x^{\circ h}(0+\varepsilon)$ for some small $h =1 \ldots 8$ to deduce the limit for $h \to \infty$ - of course if I'm not messing again ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

With some rough experimentation, one has the following result for the “experimental $-\infty$ tetration” using [**this computation**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28pi%2Beulergamma+i%2C+log%28pi%2Beulergamma+i%2C+log%28pi%2Beulergamma+i%2C+log%28pi%2Beulergamma+i%2C0%29%29%29%29) and the [sign function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function):

$$\log_{a+bi}\left(\log_{a+bi}\left(\log_{a+bi}\left(0\right)\right)\right)=\frac{\infty}{\text{sgn}(\ln(a+bi))}$$

It does not matter if you define $\ln(-\infty)=\infty+\pi i$ or $\ln(-\infty)=\infty$, for any amount $n>2$ logarithms nestings, you get the following:

$$\,^{-\infty}x\mathop=^\text{def}\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\log_x\left(…\log_x(0)\right)}_n= \frac{\infty}{\text{sgn}(\ln(x))}=\frac{\sqrt{\text{Re}^2(\ln(x))+\text{Im}^2(\ln(x))}}{\ln(x)}\infty$$

You may think that this is useless because it diverges, but the rate of divergence is proportional and is called the [Directed Infinity function](https://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/DirectedInfinity/):

$$\text{DirectedInfinity}(x)\mathop=^\text{def} \infty x\implies \,^{-\infty}x = \text{DirectedInfinity}\left(\frac{1}{\text{sgn}(\ln(x))}\right) $$

which is a complex number times infinity.

One [property](https://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/DirectedInfinity/16/02/) of $\infty x$ is that:

$$\infty x=\infty \text{sgn}(x)\implies \infty\text{sgn}\left(\frac{1}{\text{sgn}(\ln(x))}\right)= \frac{\infty}{\text{sgn}(\ln(x))} $$

Here is a complex plot of $$\frac{1}{\text{sgn}(\ln(x+yi))} :$$
[image]

Here are some values of this function:

$$\frac{\infty}{\text{sgn}(\ln(2))}=\infty$$

$$\frac{\infty}{\text{sgn}(\ln(-2))}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi^2+\ln^2(2)}}{\ln(2)+\pi i}\infty$$

$$\frac{\infty}{\text{sgn}(\ln(i))}=-\infty i$$

$$\frac{\infty}{\text{sgn}(\ln(2))}=\infty$$

$$\frac{\infty}{\text{sgn}(\ln(2-3i))}=\frac{i\sqrt{\ln^2(13)+4\tan^{-1}\left(\frac32\right)^2}}{2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac32\right)+i\ln(13)}\infty$$

Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: If you have a better answer, then I will probably accept it.